# Need to put 3 max numbers from each 3 matrix into 1 single matrix in C programing

Tags: c, matrix

Matrix A

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Matrix B

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Matrix C

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Max row numbers from all the matrix are `3 6 9`

So i would like to make the finall matrix to look like this

```
3 6 9
3 6 9
3 6 9
```

So far i did this.The code below is only for 1 matrix they all look the same.

```
int a[10][10],b[10][10],c[10][10],x[10][10],maxa[10],maxb[10],maxc[10];
int i,j,n=3;

printf("Matrix A\n");
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        scanf("%i", &a[i][j]);
    }
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++,puts("")){
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        printf("%3i", a[i][j]);
    }
}

maxa[10]=a[0][0];
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        if(maxa[10]<a[i][j]){
            maxa[10]=a[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("Max nr A[%i,%i] = %i\n",i+1,j, maxa[10]);
}
```

This is the problem. It didnt show me the 3 max row numbers. Only the highest.

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%d", maxa[10]);
}
```

As for the desired matrix i went with this.

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++,puts("")){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            x[i][j]=maxa[i]+maxb[i]+maxc[i];
            printf("%3i", x[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

And it gives me this result.

```
27 45 45
45 45 45
45 45 45
```

I have  questions. 
Why does it give me this result?
How can it show me all the max row numbers from a matrix?
How can i insert all the max row numbers in a new matrix?

Comment: What does nr mean? Numbers? As I see max numbers are 7,8,9 from every matrix. You mean sum of the column?

Comment: I think max from each row

Comment: You're going to get hate for asking for code directly, StackOverflow is not a have someone do your homework community. Atleast try to give it a try,  with some code. Plus it's not really clear what you're asking for it seems like you're looking for the largest number per row in a matrix, try to be a clearer. You have to work with arrays and search for the biggest number in each row or array depending on what the task is(once again try to be clearer).

Comment: Thank everyone for commenting! Im new at this site. I made some clearance and hope i'll get the help i need from you people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let **a b c** are your three matrices and `result[][]` is resultant matrix.
Then you can create the final matrix by assigning the max value of every row to its corresponding index.

We can generalize this approach for any number of matrices (assuming Matrix-size==no_of_matrixes).Let **A<sub>0</sub>,A<sub>1</sub>,A<sub>1</sub>,A<sub>3</sub>...A<sub>n-1</sub>** all are `n x n` matrices then the max value of the `i`th row of the **A<sub>j</sub>** th  matrix `(0<= i,j < n)` will be assigned to **(j , i)** index of the resultant matrix.

Here is the code:

```
int a[3][3],b[3][3],c[3][3],result[3][3];
int max,n=3;

//for first row
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    max=0;
    //calculating max value for each row
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        if(max<a[i][j])
        max=a[i][j];
    }
    result[0][i]=max;
}

//for second row
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    max=0;
    //calculating max value for each row
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        if(max<b[i][j])
        max=b[i][j];
    }
    result[1][i]=max;
}

//for third row
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    max=0;
    //calculating max value for each row
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        if(max<c[i][j])
        max=c[i][j];
    }
    result[2][i]=max;
}
```